# CSS Border bug is causing my whole website to show with a border. How do I fix?

Tags: html, css, border, padding

I have the following Problem:

for a while now my Website started showing a border all around it. Sadly I don't know when so I can't find a backup which was not bugged. I probably tried everything but I cannot fix it. Here is the start of my css code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #777;
}

.all-area {
    overflow: hidden;
}

section,
.section {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 0 5%;
}
```

The problem should be in this part, right? I am new to CSS (like very new) but I tried putting a div before my body and even that would appear withhin the border, so It would not stick on the upper left side of the screen. 
Here is the start of my HTML so you can see the classes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- The above 4 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <!-- Title  -->
    <title>RRive - Home</title>

    <!-- Favicon  -->
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/icon/rrive-favicon3.png">

    <!-- ***** All CSS Files ***** -->

    <!-- Style css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">

    <!-- Responsive css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">

</head>
<body class="miami">
    <!--====== Preloader Area Start ======-->
    <div id="loader">
        <div class="spinner">
            <div class="dot1"></div>
            <div class="dot2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--====== Preloader Area End ======-->
    <!--====== Scroll To Top Area Start ======-->
    <div id="scrollUp" title="Scroll To Top">
        <i class="icofont-bubble-up"></i>
    </div>
    <!--====== Scroll To Top Area End ======-->
    <div class="all-area">
        <!-- ***** Header Start ***** -->
        <header class="section header-area">
```

A guy who tried fixing it told me it was a padding I had on my body which was causing the problem, but there is no padding on my body, as far as I can see. I even tried adding padding 0 and margin 0 to some classes in css trying to find the one that was causing it but obviously no luck there...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: please provide full html code or working demo